# React app I can't fetch data from database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

When I fetch data from database firstly return empty array after that undefined also my redux state is empty, here is my code

```
    const Posts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);
  console.log(`api call ${posts}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <div>Posts</div>;
};
```

here is redux action

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.apiGetPosts;
    dispatch({ type: types.GET_POSTS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(await api.apiGetPosts);
  }
};
```

my api code

```
const apiEndpoint = "http://localhost:5000/posts";

export const apiGetPosts = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`api error ${error}`);
  }
};
```

my controller

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find();
  res.status(200).json(posts);
};
```

Comment: _"await api.apiGetPosts;"_... you're missing `()` in order to call the function